# activar una funcion desde una api

Tags: javascript, api, dom

Buenas noches necesito que cuando usen una API esta venga y modifique el DOM de la pagina que esta abierta por el usuario sin recargar pagina, me pueden porfa decir si es posible y como se prodria lograr en javascript.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ajax... o cualquier framework como angular, react, vue.... tambien podrias con jquery... y alguna otra cosa... hay mil posibilidades...

Comment: Harías una petición a esa API y una vez tienes los datos, modificarías el DOM con js para tener los datos que quieres tener de la manera en que quieres que se muestren. La API no va a modificar el DOM automáticamente.

Comment: Cargar contenido sin recargar la página-->https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/cargar-contenido-sin-recargar-la-pagina/